# cakephp 2.0 Email Debug is not working

Tags: debugging, email, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am implementing the email functionality and its also working fine . Now i have to debug in local so had done some changes as shown below
in app/config/email.php i have created this

```
public $test = array(
        'from' => 'you@localhost',
        'transport' => 'Debug',
    );
```

Now in my controller i have write the below code

```
            $Email = new CakeEmail('test');

        $email->template('adddoctor', 'add');

        //$email->emailFormat('html');


        $email->from('sender@example.com');

        $email->to('recipient@example.com');//$data['User']['email_id'];

        $email->subject('Account Detail');


        $email->send();
```

after sending mail it redirects to the index page . so in index.ctp file i have write

```
<?php echo $this->Session->flash('email'); ?>
```

i dont want to send actual mail but i just only want to show it. 
so can any one tell me which changes still i have to do for email debug ?
here some has given the answer
[CakeEmail debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797318/cakeemail-debug)

but dont understand where to write that code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you need to do to have your emails saved to the log, which is related to the solution for the other question you are trying to implement:

**app/Config/email.php**

```
public $test = array(
    'log' => true
);
```

**Your Controller**

```
$Email = new CakeEmail('test');
$email->template('adddoctor', 'add');
$email->from('sender@example.com');
$email->to('recipient@example.com');
$email->subject('Account Detail');
$email->send();
```

If you then go into **app/tmp/logs/debug.log** you will see an entry for your email, which includes the headers and message

```
2012-11-27 14:37:47 Debug: 
From: My Site <me@example.com>
X-Mailer: CakePHP Email
Date: Tue, 27 Nov 2012 14:37:47 +0000
Message-ID: <50ad02b4b1fba42733cc02456a@example.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
My message
```

However, in my opinion this is all fairly useless unless you want to see the headers.  For a start, you can't actually 'see' what your email will look like, and secondly, the email will continue to send to the recipient.

If you want to see what the actual layout/CSS of your email looks like you are probably better off just sending yourself some test emails.

I don't know why Cake got rid of the old email debugging functionality, as it was more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
$Email = new CakeEmail('test');
$email->template('adddoctor', 'add');
```

You're creating object as `$Email` and using as `$email` is it typo?

Answer (score 1):

```
$response = $Email->send();

$response['headers']; // headers as string
$response['message']; // message body with attachments

$this->Session->setFlash($response['headers'].$response['message']);
```

Make sure you have the following in your layout file.

```
echo $this->Session->flash();
```